# _ga cookie gets domain prefix added with every page refresh

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

[image]

Whenever I reload the page, a new GA1 value gets added to the cookie. I am using google tag manager (client and server-side), but nothing I change has had any impact.

I expect the cookie value to stay the same within the session.

Any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: Very strange, can you provide me the url of website where I can see this behavior?